# Why we multiply the density instead of taking the integral?

Tags: probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I am trying to understand a specific part of how we derive the Likelihood function. The likelihood is defined as:
$$
L(\theta|y_i) = k(y_i)Pr(y_i|\theta) \\
\propto Pr(y_i|\theta)  = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f_N(y_i|\theta)
$$
We can drop $k(y_i)$ as it is not a function of $\theta$, which is the parameter of interest. $Pr(y_i|\theta)$ is the probability of the data $y_i$ conditional on $\theta$. We then move on to multiply all the individual probability densities (assume Gaussian), $f_N(y_i|\theta)$, of each $n$  observation. Why are we multiplying the density value of each observation? A density is not a probability.

We know that a probability of a realized event a of a random variable A, $Pr(A = a)$, does not equal its probability density (assume Gaussian again), $f_N(a)$. We derive the probability, $Pr(a)$, from its cumulative probability distribution $F_A=\int_{-\infty}^{a}  f_N(x)dx$. Therefore, $Pr(a \in A)=\int_{A}f_N(x)dx$.

So how come that $Pr(y_i|\theta)$ equals $\prod_{i=1}^{n} f_N(y_i|\theta)$ as this is the PDF. I want to equal it to the integral $F_Y=\int_{Y}  f_N(x)dx$, which is the CDF. What am I missing in my understanding?

Comment: It seems like your $Pr(y | \theta)$ is a density, not a probability, so some of your confusion may be because of a poor notation that calls a density a probability? People will often call the joint density of a sample the "probability" of the data but that isn't meant to be technically true

Comment: @Chaconne, you are probably correct, but then under what conditions can we shift from talking about a probability to a density? I am deriving my original question after having read Gary King's Unifying Political Methodology, ch 2 and 3. He derives Likelihood från traditional probability, $Pr(x)$. See G-books for [ch 2](https://books.google.se/books?id=1SrFis-L0IIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=sv&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). I have also seen a similar notation in other textbooks.